# How can I redirect to a Create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**Ruby Version: 2.0.0**

**Rails Version: 4.0.1**

I have a controller to handle the Paypal Express Checkout workflow. When paypal reports a successful payment, I want to go ahead and `create` an order. This is my current attempt:

```
def do_express_checkout
    ##
    # Paypal logic ommited to keep this from being lengthy....
    ##
    @do_express_checkout_payment_response = api.do_express_checkout_payment(@do_express_checkout_payment) if request.post?
    if @do_express_checkout_payment_response.success?
        redirect_to controller: :orders, action: :create, method: :post
    end
end
```

The routing is the default rails routing:

```
resources :orders
```

Right now, this is just redirecting to `/orders` (the index method). **What should I do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot redirect to a `POST` action. `redirect_to` works only for `GET` requests.
With `resources :orders` , routes for `create` and `index` look exactly same except the `HTTP` verb :

```
 orders GET    /orders(.:format)                      orders#index
        POST   /orders(.:format)                      orders#create
```

When you do

```
redirect_to controller: :orders, action: :create, method: :post
```

it generates a `GET` request for `/orders` which goes to `index` action. `method` is not a valid option for `redirect_to` so it is ignored.

An *ugly workaround* would be, to create a duplicate route for `create` action with a `GET` verb:

```
  resources :orders
  get "create", to: "orders#create", as: :create_order
```

This will create a route as:

```
 create_order GET    /create(.:format)                      orders#create
```

Then you can update `do_express_checkout` method as below:

```
if @do_express_checkout_payment_response.success?
    redirect_to create_order_path
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Any idea how I can circumvent this?

Comment: I have added a workaround in my answer. Try that out.

Comment: Excellent. That is a bit dirty, but you answered my question, and for that I'll mark this as accepted. Thanks a ton for the info! (I may end up backtracking and see if I can do something a bit more permanent though)

Comment: That would be a better idea. :)